# php code of adding a record to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a control panel (admin pages) for a website. All the pages have the same code with little changes in the database table name and columns. All of them work fine, but one page doesn't work.

This is its code....

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

// read the input data
$KTitle   = $_POST['Title'];
$Kcontent = $_POST['content'];
$ImgName  = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

//get img extension
$ImgExtension = substr($ImgName, (strlen($ImgName) - 4), strlen($ImgName));
//check if it Gif, Bng, Jpg
if ($ImgExtension == ".gif" || $ImgExtension == ".jpg" || $ImgExtension == ".png")
{ //get img name to rename it then readd the extinsion
    $ImgName      = substr($ImgName, 0, (strlen($ImgName) - 4));
    $storyImgName = $ImgName . "_" . $Title;
    $target       = "../CharacterImgs/" . $storyImgName . $ImgExtension;
    $target       = str_replace(" ", "_", $target);

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO CharactersN (name,desc,img) VALUES ('$KTitle', '$Kcontent','$target')");

    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;URL=AddCharacterForm.php\">";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post what error are you getting?

Comment: I hope you are aware that your code has SQL injections there? Please top using the outdated `mysql_*` functions and learn how to work with [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and prepared statements.

Comment: This is a minor issue, but `$KTitle   = $_POST['Title'];` should probably be `$KTitle   = $_POST['title'];` (unless you send your title as `&Title=` rather than the standard `&title=`).

Comment: Doesn't work? What is it that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem here:

```
INSERT INTO CharactersN (name,desc,img)
```

`desc` is a reserved word, so you must use the ` notation there, which is like this:

```
INSERT INTO CharactersN (`name`,`desc`,`img`)
```

It is a good practice to use this notation for field names every time (or never use reserved words for field names in your database design).

---

Also, please read about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), because your code shows you are not aware of it. You are inserting values into your query which are coming from outside (POST in this case).

```
VALUES ('$KTitle', '$Kcontent','$target')")
```

You should escape these values first with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), or even better, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for your database interaction.

[image]
from [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: one could counter that "stop using reserver works as field names" is a better practice ..

Comment: @tereško I don't want to start a comment war with this, but for an inexperienced user, who might happen not to know all the reserved words, it seems to be better to use the right notation instead. Still, I edited your comment into my answer.

Comment: agreed. on another note : `mysql_escape_string()` is **deprecated**. They now have `mysql_real_escape_string()` .. which is just another sign of how old `mysql_*` has become. You should edit the answer a bit.

Comment: @tereško Thanks, that was actually a typo. Before using PDO, I was more accustomed to typing it :).

Answer (score 4):

If you use `desc` as a column name in MySQL, you must surround it in backticks because it is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

```
"INSERT INTO CharactersN (name, `desc`, img) ..."
```